# Android do not scan NFC during device rotation

Tags: android, rotation, nfc

I have an application that uses NFC. When the Activity is created and enableForegroundDispatch() has been called, the NFC is scanned and accepted by my application. However, when the NFC is scanned DURING rotation (meaning the Activity has not been created yet, and enableForegroundDispatch() was not yet called), the default Android NFC scanner takes over displaying the "New tag collected" screen.

Is there any way to carry over the enableForegroundDispatch() even during device rotation? Or is there a way to temporarily "block" the default Android NFC capability when the device is being rotated?

Thanks

EDIT: The application only accepts the NFC scan when it is running. Scanning the NFC while the app is not running only displays a "New tag collected" screen

Comment: What about running a service.

Comment: From what  I know, using a Service to handle NFC functionalities is not supported currently.

Comment: Is this tag something specific to your application? Can you encode the NDEF message on the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's different possibilities:

**Set screen orientation** for your activity

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

**Tell android not restart activity** when device rotation :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

> If your application doesn't need to update resources during a specific
>   configuration change and you have a performance limitation that
>   requires you to avoid the activity restart, then you can declare that
>   your activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents
>   the system from restarting your activity.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you use applying `android:configChanges`. You have to manage yourself screen rotation as explained in doc :

> Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not
>   restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to
>   onConfigurationChanged(). This method is passed a Configuration object
>   that specifies the new device configuration. By reading fields in the
>   Configuration, you can determine the new configuration and make
>   appropriate changes by updating the resources used in your interface.
>   At the time this method is called, your activity's Resources object is
>   updated to return resources based on the new configuration, so you can
>   easily reset elements of your UI without the system restarting your
>   activity.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. However, my app HAS to rotate, and applying android:configChanges somehow affects the layout for portrait and landscape.

Comment: @mugiwara528, Is it useful ?

Comment: Hi, yes it is useful. However, we chose a different approach to the problem.

Comment: @mugiwara528 If your "different approach" solves the problem (for you) you might want to add it as an answer to your own question since it may also help others.